# Does the expansion of the universe have any effects in the kinetic Sunyaev-Zeldovich effect?

Tags: electromagnetism, cosmology, photons, space-expansion, scattering

Photons can be blueshifted after being scattered by excited free electrons in galaxy clusters (Sunyaev-Zeldovich effect).

The kinetic version of this effect occrus because electrons are accelerated. I've read that the kinetic SZ signal is sensitive to both the expansion history and the dynamics of cosmological perturbations... But I don't understand this completely...

Therefore, does the expansion of the universe affect this in some way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does space expansion not expand matter?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/why-does-space-expansion-not-expand-matter)

Comment: @D.Halsey:  I don't see how that question discusses the Sunayev-Zeldovich effect, or any effects involving the scattering of photons.